# Как правильно написать скрипт?

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно написать скрипт который выводит имя пользователя, домашний каталог. Добавляет в архив все файлы домашнего каталога. Если архив с таким именем уже существует, то вывести предуприждение.

```
#! /bin/bash

who=$(whoami);
echo "Пользователь системы: $who";
echo "Домашний каталог: $HOME";

first=$(ls *back_up_name_$(date +%A).zip*);  
second="back_up_name_$(date +%A).zip";

if [ $first -eq $second ]; then 
    read -p "Переписать файл? (1/0)" choise;

    if [$choise -eq 1]; then 
        zip back_up_name_$(date +%A).zip
        else exit 0
    fi

    else 
    zip back_up_name_$(date +%A).zip; 
fi

exit 0;
```

Некорректно работает, не могу разобраться почему.

Comment: Это переменная по идее. Нашел такую строчку в каком то мануале.

Comment: А что конкретно работает не так?

Comment: проверка существования файла проще `if [ -f имя_файла ] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, дело в отсутствии пробелов у квадратных скобок?

```
if [ $choise -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. if [ -f имя_файла ] - это также помогло упростить жизнь.